# if xy.nil? = true?

Tags: ruby

I can't really figure out how to fit the check if `patient.kalium != nil`. If it's nil it should stop, otherwise it should go with the `if` phrase.

It always gives me the error

```
block (3 levels) in top (required)
```

This is the code:

```
patient.medications.each do |m|   
  unless !patient.kalium.nil?
    if m.medi.atc =~ /^C01AA05/ && patient.kalium(m.startdat)<2.8 &&  #prüfen ob patient.kalium.nil? dann nicht weiter ausführen.
      dig_k+=1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `&&` what? You need to specify another clause or remove that.

Comment: thanks, i realized that after posting it. but it doesn't solve the error unfortunatly

Comment: Try and clean up the example code here to better reflect what's actually going on. If you're battling a syntax error it's important to know what the exact issue is.

Comment: It make me nervous that were are talking about patient medications.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You need a better title, one that explains the question, not just a bit of pseudocode.

Comment: kalium overdose @Meier

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the confusing world of double negation.

This

```
unless !patient.kalium.nil?
  if m.medi.atc
```

will execute the `if` block only if `patient.kalium` is nil.

Just get rid of the `!`:

```
unless patient.kalium.nil?
  if m.medi.atc
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks frank! i tried it, but i still get the odd "block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'" for the patients.medications.each.do

and a block (2 levels) for the "unless !patient..." 

do you think something is wrong with the code or what does the error mean?;) 

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like `if patient.kalium != nil` then you can just do it like this:

```
if patient.kalium != nil 
  # calculate something using patient.kalium
end
```

You can express this in many different ways, and many Ruby programmers would prefer `unless patient.kalium.nil?`  but obviously this has confused you.

And, doing medical software, you should not do confusing things. You should be able to look at the code and immediately see that it is doing what you intended to do.